# Snakemake - Google Cloud Preemptible instances

Tags: snakemake

I see from the docs that Snakemake has Google Cloud support, but can it be configured to make use of preemptible instances?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only difference between preemptible instances and standard ones lie in their availability. An excerpt from the [preemptible VM documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible):

> Preemptible instances function like normal instances but have the
> following limitations:
>
> Compute Engine might terminate preemptible instances at any time due
> to system events. The probability that Compute Engine will terminate a
> preemptible instance for a system event is generally low, but might
> vary from day to day and from zone to zone depending on current
> conditions.
>
> Compute Engine always terminates preemptible instances
> after they run for 24 hours. Certain actions reset this 24-hour
> counter.
>
> Preemptible instances are finite Compute Engine resources, so
> they might not always be available.

You can follow snakemake's guide for google cloud execution. Personally I have almost exclusively used preemptible instances (even for Google Kubernetes Engine) for my snakemake jobs.

Whether your pipeline is suited to using preemptible instances depends on **how long it will run and if it is tolerant of random interruptions** due to the VM shutting down. You will have to monitor regularly to check if the VM is still running, start it up again and restart your pipeline.

Another thing that deals well with preemptibles is running snakemake with the `--ri` argument (short for rerun incomplete) when starting up the pipeline again. Also, if the pipeline was terminated due to the VM shutting down, you will probably have to run snakemake with `--unlock` before resuming the pipeline.

I'm not sure if there's any underlying questions, but your question is mildly vague. It's best to edit it and provide more detail of your use case, how you intended to make use of the preemptible instances and what sort of configurations you had in mind. Here I've assumed that you meant *running* snakemake on a preemptible, in which case it can be treated just like a regular machine (except that it will shut down at least once within 24h).